# How do I comment on an answer in StackExchange sites (e.g., StackOverflow) and what StackExchange site should I have asked this on?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

How do I comment on an answer in StackExchange sites (e.g., StackOverflow) and what StackExchange site should I have asked this question on?

Comment: earn more reputation and you can comment on others post too

Comment: See CompuChip's answer you need 50 reputation to post the comment on someone's post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commenting on others' posts is a privilege that will be unlocked when you gain reputation. I think the feature is enabled when you reach 50 reputation.

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges for the full list.